# Firebase Instant Sync not working properly

Tags: angularjs, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have `$scope.Visits` from parent `controller` and then through `ng-repeat` in each `Visits` instance have own scope and own `controller`.Every instance in own controller fetch a `Employee` object from `firebase-database`. but problem is that when I change data of that `Employee` object from `firebase-database` it does not change data on view but when I change 2nd time it shows previous change but not the current change 
Im pulling a single Object from `firebase-database` in AngularFire as shown below

```
var empRefIN = firebase.database().ref('Employees/' + $scope.VMS.$id + '/' + Object.keys($scope.visit.Employee)[0])

$scope.employeeINDetail = $firebaseObject(empRefIN);
```

and here is my HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="visit in Visits" ng-controller="INCtrl" ng-if="visit.Status=='IN'">

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-7" style="margin:0 auto;margin-top:5px;">
         <p>

              <b >{{employeeINDetail.empName}}</b> 

         </p>


 </div>
```